# 1991 Honda Civic 4WD wagon needs new computer. Where can I find one to replace?

Tags: honda, civic

The local Honda dealership diagnosed the computer has died and they say the part is no longer available. No way I am going to accept this answer. The car only has 130 K on her. Is this a fairly straight forward installation, if found?

Answer (score 5):

Aftermarket, check your local parts store. It looks like A1 Cardone makes one. You will have to check your local parts store. You will also need the OEM number from the original computer.

[image]

[A1 Cardone](http://www.cardone.com/find-parts/vehicle-parts-listing?make=Honda&model=Civic&year=1991)

You can also check local junk yards.

It's normal for dealers not to carry parts for cars that old, some parts are disconinuied from the manufacture as early as 10 years.

Answer (score 0):

Your vehicle had a short production run some time ago. Developments since 1991 on vehicle electronic controls have been immense. For your Honda dealer to say the ECU for your vehicle is unobtainable would be pretty reasonable.

You still have a couple of options though. Your dealer may have a sub-contractor who would be able to repair your ECU, or introduce you to a company that repairs ECU's. Your dealer may be willing to purchase a used ECU 'off the net' and install it for you. These options would keep the costs involved reasonable.

A final option would be to be contact an after-market supplier of ECU's to supply and fit an alternative ECU installation. The cost of this would most likely be prohibitive.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in any wrecking yards?  For anything over 20 years old, particularly a mass production vehicle like a civic, I would look for a used part.  The first thing to do is determine what the engine configuration is because you may not need an exact model match to get a part that will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

**NAPA** carries reman computers for your vehicle.  They are buying them from A1 Cardone and would most likely be a special order item that might take a couple days to get shipped in.  Looks like there are 5 options split mostly along the lines of *Auto. vs Manual* and *California Emissions vs Federal*.